# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Express, Mongoose Server Crash

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose

I'm working on a user authentication backend with express & mongoose.

I am trying to sort out the ability for users to update their name and email address.

So I'm checking if the email matches the current users email, then if not, checking if it matches any other users email. If it does, then I throw an error, if it doesn't then I save it to the user.

The name updates fine, and the email updates fine (except when a user already has been called.)

The error message sends to the client, but also crashes the server with "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT" and I cannot for the life of me figure out why as I am returning the error.

Here is the code:

```js
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  // Get New User Details
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = req.body;

  // Find User
  User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'User not found.'
      });
    }
    user.firstName = firstName;
    user.lastName = lastName;

    // Check to see if another user has this email.
    if (email !== user.email) {
      User.findOne({ email: email }).exec((err, existingUser) => {

        // If they do, send an error message.
        if (!err && existingUser) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: "This email address is already in use.",
          });
        }

        // If they don't, send alert email to old email address.

      });

      // Finally update email address.
      user.email = email;
    }

    // Save Updated User Information
    user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: Could not update user.");
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: 'User update failed.'
        });
      }
      updatedUser.hashedPassword = undefined;
      updatedUser.salt = undefined;
      return res.json({
        message: ' Account updated successfully.',
        data: updatedUser
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it:

```js
// Update User Account Data
// ========================
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  // Get New User Details
  const { firstName, lastName, email } = req.body;

  // Find User
  User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'User not found.'
      });
    }

    if (email !== user.email) {
      User.findOne({ email: email }).exec((err, existingUser) => {

        // If they do, send an error message.
        if (!err && existingUser) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: "This email address is already in use.",
          });
        }

        // If they don't, send alert email to old email address.

        // Finally update user.
        user.firstName = firstName;
        user.lastName = lastName;
        user.email = email;

        // Save Updated User Information
        user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error: Could not update user.");
            return res.status(400).json({
              error: 'User update failed.'
            });
          }
          updatedUser.hashedPassword = undefined;
          updatedUser.salt = undefined;
          return res.json({
            message: ' Account updated successfully.',
            data: updatedUser
          });
        });

      });
    } else {
      user.firstName = firstName;
      user.lastName = lastName;

      // Save Updated User Information
      user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error: Could not update user.");
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'User update failed.'
          });
        }
        updatedUser.hashedPassword = undefined;
        updatedUser.salt = undefined;
        return res.json({
          message: ' Account updated successfully.',
          data: updatedUser
        });
      });
    }
  });
};
```